# Why is Manipulation not creating a graph?

Tags: manipulate, export, code-review, gif-format

Why does manipulation not give a graph?

```
Remove[y];
Remove[b];
n = 1;
k = 1;
j = Solve[k*y*(1 - y/n) - b == 0, {y}]
o[b_] := Evaluate[y /. j]
s = DSolve[y'[t] == k*y[t]*(1 - y[t]/n) - b, y[t], t];
f[t_, b_, c_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. s]
sol = Table[f[t, b, c], {c, -5, 5}]
d=Manipulate[Plot[sol, {t, -5, 5}], {b, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

How do we correct this? How would I turn this into a gif?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we correct this? How would I turn this into a gif?

One question at a time please. For the first part, your code is not that easy to follow. Below I will only make it work, without rewriting completely (no time).

First, you need to set the constant of integration correctly. Also fix Manipulate to make it work right. This below does that

```
ClearAll[y, b, c, t, k, n];
n = 1;
k = 1;
j = Solve[k*y*(1 - y/n) - b == 0, {y}];
o[b_] := Evaluate[y /. j];
s = DSolve[y'[t] == k*y[t]*(1 - y[t]/n) - b, y[t], t];
f[t_, b_, c_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. s] /. C[1] -> c;
sol = Table[f[t, b, c], {c, -5, 5}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[sol /. {t -> t0, b -> b0}, {t0, -5, 5}],
 {b0, 1, 5},
 TrackedSymbols :> {b0}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Are you sure you want to plot all the solutions at same time? For one c, you can do

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[sol[[1,1]] /. {t -> t0, b -> b0}, {t0, -5, 5}],
 {b0, 1, 5},
 TrackedSymbols :> {b0}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could add a control to decide which `c` you want to plot the solution for.

For exporting to animated gif, if you search this forum, there are plenty of solutions showing how to do this.